# css transform: translate just not working both back and fort

Tags: css, css-transitions

I use transform: translate on some boxes. When I push a button it suppose to slide down over the box below exept for the last box which slides up. This works fine but when I what it to slide the outer way it only works on the one that slides the other way (the last item) the others just disappear.

```
.ditales {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  &.active {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &.not-active {
    transform: translate(0, 0%);
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
&:last-child {
  .ditales{
    &.active {
      transform: translate(0, -100%);
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
}
```

The active and not-active class is added and removed whit jQuery

```
//play button
$(this).parent().find('.case-ditales').removeClass('not-active').addClass('active');

//Stop button and when play button are pushed in another box
 $('.ditales').removeClass('active').addClass('not-active');
```

[example on codepen](https://codepen.io/JohannaL/pen/LyYaQE)

EDIT:

I realized that it's not the transform: translate thats the problem it's because the ditales box z-index needs to bee more then the box it's overlaying and the z-index sets to 0 on not-active.
Is there a way to fix this? (pleas se the link whit the code)

Comment: Make us a working sample

Comment: Looks like a nesting issue to me, shouldn’t `&:last-child` be placed inside `.ditales`?

Comment: @LarsBeck it works on the one inside last-child, is the outers that dosen't work.

Comment: @LGSon I added a sample now

Comment: I rollbacked your inclusion of the solution in the question itself. You may still find [it in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9435892f-7e41-4d8c-b00a-260b5756b58a/view-source). Please post it as an answer of its own, thank you.